# How to connect a 240x320 37-pin TFT to an Arduino Nano?

Tags: arduino-nano, tft

I have an old TFT display (extracted from an MP5 player) and I can't figure out how to connect it with an arduino nano, pls help.
here's the datasheet of the TFT:
http://read.pudn.com/downloads137/sourcecode/embed/586271/Varitronix-2.8-lcd/vl-ps-cog-t280mbqi-041.pdf
Thank you.

Comment: The datasheet says it all: A ILI9320 display driver with a 16-bit data bus (instead of SPI). Can you show a picture of the display and the connections? It's pretty close to https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-3-5-color-320x480-tft-touchscreen-breakout/8-bit-wiring-and-test. (8bit). If no 16-bit parallel driver is available you'll have to look at the ILI9320 datahseet and build one. However, if your objective is just to get a display for an Arduino, just buy a new well-known display with a simple SPI interface for which there are drivers.

Comment: Is this datasheet hosted on the end of a 56k dialup modem...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Nano isn't a good choice for driving that screen. You need almost all the pins of the Nano to connect to the screen alone, and there's not enough to include the touch-screen as well. And that's when you're *not* using the serial port of the Arduino (TX/RX pins) for communication with the PC.

You need to connect:

- 16 data pins
- /CS pin
- /RS pin
- /WR pin
- Optionally RD pin, or tie it to 3.3V
- /RESET pin

And all those need to be level shifted to 3.3V.

You need to provide 3.3V to VCC1/2 and VCI.  The LED A connects to 5V (since it has more current capacity than the 3.3V) and each LED Kx pin through a suitable resistor (220Ω maybe) to ground.

The touchscreen needs the X- and Y- pins connecting to a digital IO pin, and the X+ and Y+ pins to analog IO pins that can also double as digital IO pins (so not A6/A7 on boards that have them).

And then you need to obtain or write the software to drive the ILI9320 through the 16-bit interface.

Driving the interface is simple enough:

Initially:

1. Set /CS HIGH
2. Set /WR HIGH
3. Set /RD HIGH (if not tied to 3.3V)
4. Set /RESET HIGH
5. Short delay
6. Set /RESET LOW
7. Short delay
8. Set /RESET HIGH

Then to transfer a group of 16-bit words:

1. Set /CS LOW
2. Set the value to write on the 16 data pins
3. Pulse /WR LOW then HIGH
4. Repeat from 2 for each word
5. Set /CS HIGH

Refer to the ILI9320 datasheet for how to control the chip, or use existing library code (does uTFT or u8glib support it?).

For the touch screen it's a case of setting Y- LOW and Y+ HIGH, and X- and X+ to INPUT, then reading the analog value from X+.  Repeat with X- set LOW and X+ set HIGH, and both Y set to INPUT, and read the analog value from Y+.

You can also get better results by reading multiple inverted settings:

- Y- = LOW, Y+ = HIGH, X- = INPUT, Read X+.
- Y- = HIGH, Y- = LOW, X- = INPUT, Read X+.
- Subtract the second reading from 1023
- Add the first and (modified) second reading
- Divide by two.
- Repeat for X-/X+ reading from Y+.

You can also take multiple readings and average them out to reduce noise and stabilise the output somewhat.

And of course on top of all that you need to find a way to connect to a 0.5mm pitch connector. Normally a 0.5mm pitch FPC socket is used, which means a PCB with one on.  You may be able to find 37 pin adaptor for it, but 37 pins isn't a common format.  Normally 50 pin is more common to accommodate a more general purpose interface including the M0-M2 pins that allow you to select the interface type, as well as an 18-bit data bus to allow full RGB6/6/6 interfacing, and even buffer-less clocking of raw display data for very high speed display updates by MCUs that support such an interface.

Comment: I'll try it later (can't do it now because my computer is toast), thank you for your help by the way. i'll tell you later if it worked.